# Delete particular mp3 files in a directory that has no metadata(Title,artist etc)?

Tags: python, information-retrieval

I want to delete particular mp3 files in a directory that has no metadata(Title, artist, etc). I tried sorting the files and then deleting it manually but it didn't work as the number of files is huge(~30K). Is there any python script to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example script is not completed, but I hope that good start point for you.

```
import os
import glob
from mutagen.easyid3 import EasyID3

mp3_files_list = glob.glob(path/to/your/mp3-files-folder/*.mp3) # example path /home/user/Downloads/mp3/*.mp3

for mp3_file in mp3_files_list:
    audio = EasyID3(mp3_file)
    if not audio['title']: # if title tag is empty
        os.remove(mp3_file)
    if not audio['artist']:
        os.remove(mp3_file)
    # etc tags check
```

Mutagen module documentation: https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/